# How can I pass a stdin as an argument for my function?

Tags: c, string, function, loops

My first program. I would like it if the user enters a word made of letters and then it uses my loop function to output mixed up even and odd characters. Currently I cannot get it to compile. Bonus points if someone can show me how to loop the users input so after it asks the size to make the array, it prompts the user that many times for an "element" or word so that the function can scramble it and output it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char transform(char str[]);

int main()
{   //Declare an array and size variable
    int size = 0;
    char str[size];
    
    
    printf("How many elements?");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    
    printf("Please type an element: ");
    //Get input from user    
    str[0] = scanf("%s", str);
    transform(str); 
    
    printf("Please type another element: ");
    //Get another input from user    
    str[1] = scanf("%s", str);
    transform(str);
    



//This is the loop function that I programmed    
char transform(char str[]);
{
    
    //Loop that prints even characters
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
    if(i % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    }   //Space between even/odd characters
        printf(" ");
    //Loop that prints odd characters    
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
    if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    }
        printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: `int size = 0; char str[size];` this is weird, you declaring a `char` array of size 0...

Comment: There are many problems, the first one is in the two first lines of `main`. You declare `str` to be a zero-sized array. Zero-sized arrays are not allowed.

Comment: also, you are missing a semicolon, your `transform` function should be outside of `main`

Comment: You are using loops to print the array elements, what prevents you to write similar loops with `scanf`? Unless you have already studied dynamic memory allocation, declare a big enough array and use only part of its elements.

Comment: `str[0] = scanf("%s", str);` is wrong. `scanf` returns an `int`, which is the number of fields succesfully retrieved (0 on fail) or EOF (end of file, usually -1). It doesn't make sense to store that value in `str[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char transform(char str[]);

int main()
{ //Declare an array and size variable
    int size = 0;

    printf("How many elements?");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        printf("Please type an element: ");

        char str[2048]; //declare a wide buffer to be able to store lots of chars
        scanf("%s", str);

        transform(str);
    }

    return 0;
} //end your main here, by putting closing brace

char transform(char str[]) //define transform without semicolon, and outside of main
{ //This is the loop function that I programmed

    //Loop that prints even characters
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            printf("%c", str[i]);
    } //Space between even/odd characters

    printf(" ");

    //Loop that prints odd characters
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
            printf("%c", str[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tony! You did it! Thank you for helping me with this. I have only been coding for a week but this little personal project has really helped. Keep an eye out, because I will be posting more, all beginner stuff. I start my computer science major next month so hopefully I will get better.